# iframe google map is not working

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, google-maps, iframe

I am using an `iFrame` to show `google-map`, but it is not working.
If I paste the URL into the browser, then it is showing the exact location.
I don't know why it is not working.

My HTML code:

```
<div><iframe src="<?php echo $uni['GoogleMapLink'];?>"  width="97%" height="50%" frameborder="0" style="border:1px solid #ccc;"></iframe></div> 

<?php echo $uni['GoogleMapLink'];?> is https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Birmingham+City+University/@52.517047,-1.897309,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x4870b
```

The output in the browser is:

```
<div><iframe src="https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Birmingham+City+University/@52.517047,-1.897309,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x4870bcf7bed14f49:0x783aa84ea9692f19"  width="97%" height="50%" frameborder="0" style="border:1px solid #ccc;"></iframe></div>
```

Comment: Could be to do with this `<?php echo $uni['GoogleMapLink'];?>` I can not see it in foreach loop we need more code to go by like the controller function etc

Comment: see my question is showing the output of <?php echo $uni['GoogleMapLink'];?>

Answer (score 0):

You are not allowed to display that URL in an iframe.  If I create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbu0kdt3/) containing your code:

```
<div><iframe src="https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Birmingham+City+University/@52.517047,-1.897309,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x4870b"  width="97%" height="50%" frameborder="0" style="border:1px solid #ccc;"></iframe></div>
```

and look in the javascript console, I see:

```
Refused to display 'https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Birmingham+City+University/@52.517047,-1.897309,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x4870b' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

You should look at the [Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/) or use Google's tools to create a map you can put on your page.